# Marginal effects of dummy predictors in logistic model in SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, effects

I'd like to derive marginal effects from categorical logistic model in SAS.
In case of continuous dependent variables, thanks for SAS manual([22604](http://support.sas.com/kb/22/604.html)), I understood how to calculate marginal effects to some extent.

However this SAS manual only handles marginal effects of continuous predictors on binary or categorical dependent variables. So I'm not sure whether manual's method can be applied in case of binary dummy predictors.

Conceptually, I can interpret marginal effects of dummy predictors on dependent variable, but technically i'm not sure it's right calculation.

Of course, it might be better to use the odd ratio. I agree, but I'd like to use and marginal effects.

Thanks for reading.

```
   data crops;
   input Crop $1-10 x1 rain $ ;
   datalines;
Corn       16 1
Corn       15 0
Corn       16 0
Corn       18 0
Corn       15 1
Corn       15 1
Corn       12 1
Soybeans   20 0
Soybeans   24 0
Soybeans   21 1
Soybeans   27 1
Soybeans   12 1
Soybeans   22 1
Cotton     31 0
Cotton     29 0
Cotton     34 0
Cotton     26 1
Cotton     53 0
Cotton     34 1
Sugarbeets 22 1
Sugarbeets 25 0
Sugarbeets 34 1
Sugarbeets 54 1
Sugarbeets 25 1
Sugarbeets 26 1
Clover     12 0
Clover     24 0
Clover     87 0
Clover     51 0
Clover     96 0
Clover     31 1
Clover     56 1
Clover     32 0
Clover     36 0
Clover     53 1
Clover     32 1
;

 proc logistic data=crops;
    class rain(ref='0');
    model crop = rain / link=glogit;

    output out=preds predprobs=individual;
    ods output ParameterEstimates=betas;
    run;
  proc transpose data=betas out=rowbetas;
    var estimate;
    run;
  data margeff;
    if _n_=1 then set rowbetas;
    set preds;
    SumBetaPred=col5*IP_Clover + col6*IP_Corn + col7*IP_Cotton + col8*IP_Soybeans;
    MEClover=IP_Clover*(col5-SumBetaPred);
    MECorn=IP_Corn*(col6-SumBetaPred);
    MECotton=IP_Cotton*(col7-SumBetaPred);
    MESoybeans=IP_Soybeans*(col8-SumBetaPred);
    MESugarbeets=IP_Sugarbeets*(-SumBetaPred);
    run;
  proc sort nodupkey;
    by rain;
    run;
  proc print;
    id rain;
    var me:;
    run;
```

Comment: Does marginal effect calculated make sense given a LOGISTIC relationship? For linear that makes sense but don't think it does given a logit model. FYI - I'm often wrong but curious.

Comment: I know what you said. Yes, a logistic model isn't linear, so marginal effects derived from partial derivative looks something wrong. I my case, I've seen economic paper using marginal effects in a logit model. In economic fields, many researchers prefer marginal effects to odd ratios, even in case of a logit model. Of course it's not linear, so they use other concept, like average marginal effects.